# Does data race exist because of the instruction pipelining of the CPU?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, cpu

As titled.

I have seen a couple of articles online regarding why data race exists but seems no one of them mentions the root cause of why a data race happens when more than one thread writes the value on the same memory location. And I assume that happens because of the instruction pipelining of CPU, the execution of each instruction would be separated into several steps (IF, ID, EX, MEM, WB), and those steps of those instructions would be executed interleaved, which causes the data race, is this understanding correct?

Comment: 'no one of them mentions the root cause of why a data race happens when more than one thread writes the value on the same memory location'.....that seems.....unlikely:(

Comment: One thing is that on many common architectures, simple reads and writes of up to a certain size, if properly aligned, are naturally atomic, and don't cause any data race to begin with.  Accesses that are larger or unaligned get broken into several atomic pieces and so *tearing* can result: when the several loads or stores of one access interleave with those of another, you may end up reading or writing a value that none of the writers intended.  That's the usual bad result of a data race.

Comment: But this is unrelated to pipelining; more to the width of the memory bus or the cache architecture.  Tearing would be an issue even on a completely in-order non-pipelined architecture.  If you like, all the sub-accesses are part of the "MEM" step.